# Linq ToList() execution

Tags: c#

I want to build a tree structure like this:

```
 root  Id 1
   child id 2
     grandChild  id 3
```

Code sample below. If I use `GetChildrenNodesCorrect(),` I get the correct result. But when `GetChildrenNodesWrong()` is used, it returns below:

```
root  Id 1
   child id 2
     Null
```

I know that `ToList()` is not deferred execution, and returns result immediatelly. Could anyone explain this?

```
 public class ToListTest
    {
       public static void Entry()
       {
           var toListTest = new ToListTest();

           toListTest.Test();

       }

       public void Test()
       {
           List<Node> newsList = new List<Node>
               {
                   new Node{Id = 1, ParentId = 0},
                   new Node{Id = 2, ParentId = 1},
                   new Node{Id = 3, ParentId = 2}
               };

          var root = BuildUpTree(newsList);
       }


        private TreeNode BuildUpTree(List<Node> newsList)
        {
            var root = new TreeNode { currentNode = newsList.First(n => n.ParentId == 0) };

            BuildUpTreeChildrenNodes(newsList, root);

            return root;
        }



        private void BuildUpTreeChildrenNodes(List<Node> newsList, TreeNode currentTreeNode)
        {

            currentTreeNode.Children = GetChildrenNodesWrong(newsList, currentTreeNode);

            foreach (var node in currentTreeNode.Children)
            {                
                BuildUpTreeChildrenNodes(newsList, node);    
            }


        }

        private  IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetChildrenNodesWrong(List<Node> newsList, TreeNode cuurentNode)
        {
            return newsList.Where(n => n.ParentId == cuurentNode.currentNode.Id)
                                .Select(n => new TreeNode
                                {
                                    currentNode = n
                                });
        }

        private IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetChildrenNodesCorrect(List<Node> newsList, TreeNode cuurentNode)
        {
            return GetChildrenNodesWrong(newsList, cuurentNode).ToList();
        }

       public class TreeNode
       {

           public Node currentNode { get; set; }
           public IEnumerable<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }

       }

       public class Node
       {

           public int Id { get; set; }
           public int ParentId { get; set; }

       }
    }
```

**Update**

In debug, when using `GetChildrenNodesWrong(),` root has both child and grandchild before the method returns. After the method returns, root has only child, and grandchild is null.

**Update 2**

IMO, the problem might not be related to clean code. But anyone is welcome to show more intuitive code.

Comment: The grandChild is null, please see my update.

Comment: +1 good question.  Consider an analogy.  Imagine you're building a legos wall.  It's important that you stack each lego on a lego that fits _and_ is part of the wall.  You are building a tree, so it's important that you build each child `TreeNode` on a `TreeNode` that is its parent _and_ is part of the tree.  `GetChildrenNodesWrong` ensures you build child `TreeNodes` on parent `TreeNodes`.  @Ben explains that `ToList` in `GetChildrenNodesCorrect` ensures that you build child `TreeNodes` on` TreeNodes` that are part of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the `IEnumerable` is evaluated the Linq query is re-executed.  So, when you're computing the tree, it is allocating space for nodes but not assigning them to any permanent variable.  This means that in the `foreach` loop in `BuildUpTreeChildrenNodes`, you are not calling the recursive function on the instance of the node you want.  Instead, you're calling it on a re-instantiated version of the node that has been created by the `foreach` loop (which enumerates the `IEnumerable`).  When you call `ToList` on the `IEnumerable` instead, then the `foreach` loop will return the elements of the list, which is in memory.

If you make `root` public static, and then debug your code, you'll see that when you call `BuildUpTreeChildrenNodes`, the `node` argument is not the instance of the node that you want. Even though it has the same ID and represents the same node in the graph, it is not actually connected in any way to the root node. Check:

```
root.Children.Any(n => n.Id == node.Id) //true
root.Children.Contains(node) //false
```

The simplest way to see your problem is here:

```
//Create a singleton Node list:
var nodeSingleton= Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(x => new Node { Id = x });
Console.Write(nodeSingleton.Single() == nodeSingleton.Single());
```

You might expect this to return `true`, but in fact it will be `false` - both times the `Single` Linq method is called, the deferred execution of the singleton variable is re-evaluated, and returns a different instance of the `Node` class.

If you call `ToList` on the singleton, however, then you get the list in memory and the `Single` method will return the same instance of the `Node`.

More broadly, I think the problem with this code is that it mixes up imperative and functional code too much.  It is strange that so many of the methods are `void` and then the `GetChildrenNodesWrong` method is not.  I think you should pick a style and stick with it, since switching paradigms can be confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Regarding your last paragraph, could you elaborate on reasons of not mixing void methods and non void methods? and its practicality.

Comment: I didn't mean to overstate that advice. It is often fine to mix different styles of programming. In fact, it is encouraged to take the best of different styles offered by C#. All I meant to say is that subtle mistakes like the one presented in your question can be avoided.  For example, if every method here were functional and used deferred execution, this problem probably would not have manifested.

Comment: I know the deferred execution, but in this case, why only grandchild is null when using the wrong method. Also, why root.Children.Contains(node) is false when it is above BuildUpTreeChildrenNodes() in the BuildUpTreeChildrenNodes() method. My understanding on this is that currentTreeNode.Children is only executed upon foreach, which produces children. Immediately, root.Children.Contains(node) is executed. Thus, it should be true.

Comment: When you call `Contains` on `root.Children` it evaluates the `Children` enumerable again. Similarly, this happens when we check the state of the tree after building the tree.

Comment: I think the culprit is that all initialized variables var deferred execution is not permanent, even they are referenced after the method returns. Is it a C# bug, or a C# improvement to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. All LINQ queries have deferred execution, when you call `ToList()` you're simply forcing the query to execute. I think the main problem is in your where clause. Only two objects satisfy the condition so the IEnumerable returned by your LINQ query should only have 2 objects.

It's not doing what you expect because the LINQ query in `GetChildrenNodesWrong` is producing an "off by one" error. Here is basically what happens;

1) we feed it root for n = root nothing happens. We move to the next node.

2) n.Id = 1, the where condition is met by node 2 as it's parentId is 1. We allocate a new node, point current to node 2

3) We get to the third node now. n.ParentId = 2 and current.Id = 2. We have a match so we allocated another node and point current to node 3.

4) we're at the end of the list. Grand child is never allocated because we're off by one.

Basically you iterate x time where x is the length of the list but because current = n on the first iteration you don't allocate a node so you end up with x -1 nodes when you're expecting x.

Comment: No, Second iteration when Id is 2, and it gets its child. What do mean by it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Sorry my original assumption was wrong, updating with correct error info.

Comment: This doesn't explain why this would work with the call to ToList

Comment: @BenReich it doesn't. `ToList` is never even called and has nothing to do with the logical errors in his method.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - the method works as desired when called with ToList (try running it locally).  ToList is called in the "Correct" version of the method provided by OP.  My post explains that this is because of the deferred execution of the IEnumerable.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal You're correct that `ToList` does not change the logic in the method.  However, you’re missing a subtle point.  `GetChildrenNodesWrong` returns a `TreeNode` that is not part of the tree.  `ToList` ensures that `GetChildrenNodesCorrect` returns a `TreeNode` that is part of the tree as Ben explains in his answer.  So I’m sorry, but I’m going to have to give this a -1 because the logic in `GetChildrenNodesWrong` is correct.  Rather, the way it’s being used is incorrect.

Comment: @steaks I don't really see the distinction. If you write it correctly GetChildrenNodes should be a single method with no more than 5 lines of code. I didn't bother to look closely at his entire program because it's not well written (no offense, but obv a project for a first year cs class), I just saw a piece of logic that doesn't really make sense. You can say it's "correct" but it's not intuitive or straight forward. A good solution would just have better logic in one place.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I agree that GetChildrenNodes could be written more intuitively.  And I think it's super useful to suggest more intuitive ways to write the function.  However, the logic is correct.  So it's misleading to say the logic is incorrect.   Moreover, the question was "Why does ToList make this code work?"  That's a great question because it's really puzzling why `ToList`, a method call that doesn't change the logic, changes the result of the code.  Therefore, I think the best answer would explain why `ToList` changes the result _and_ would provide more intuitive logic.

Comment: @steaks those are all good points but I still disagree. If the author of a piece of code is achieving a result due to a side effect which they cannot explain I would say that their logic is wrong and you should be correcting the core logic and removing whatever is causing the side effect. However, you have correctly pointed out that the question asked why `ToList` makes it work and I didn't bother to explain that. I just said correct this piece of code which honestly should still happen. Any good programmer doing a code review on that obv would not accept it.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Thank you for your points. But I am not sorry to say that I am not asking for a clean code here. So next time, please read and think before you answer any questions, and judge someone.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I've often written unintuitive code that produced errors because of unexpected side effects.  Even worse, I've sometimes refactored the my unintuitive code into more readable code that produced the same errors because of the exact same side effects.  Therefore, I think it's really important to identify what the source of errors rather than to assume that refactoring unintuitive code into intuitive code will solve my problems.  I've learned the hard way :)

Comment: @Pingpong ok, keep writing code that doesn't make sense. It will get you far in the software industry.

Comment: @pingpong "read and think before you answer any questions" -- too harsh IMO.  He gave a thorough, logical and thought out answer.  I think it was a good attempt faulted by a really difficult concept and that you should be thankful for his effort.  Sure, he could have run your code on a machine to see it execute correctly...but that seems like a pretty high standard to ask of a stranger for free.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, Apologies, but I didn't mean that way. If my code example is not intuitive enough. You are welcome to show me your code if you would like to.